# Get value of object

Tags: php, class, object

I don't get it... I have this object:

```
object(stdClass)#7 (12) {
 ["type"]=> int(0) 
 ["encoding"]=> int(1)
 ["ifsubtype"]=> int(1)
 ["subtype"]=> string(5) "PLAIN"
 ["ifdescription"]=> int(0)
 ["ifid"]=> int(0) 
 ["lines"]=> int(44) 
 ["bytes"]=> int(1078) 
 ["ifdisposition"]=> int(0) 
 ["ifdparameters"]=> int(0) 
 ["ifparameters"]=> int(1) 
 ["parameters"]=> array(1) 
       { [0]=> object(stdClass)#8 (2) 
            { ["attribute"]=> string(7) "charset" 
              ["value"]=> string(5) "utf-8" } } }
```

and want to get `"parameters" -> "value"` (last lines)

I get "parameters" like this:

```
public function get_formated_body() {
        return $this->format->parameters;
    }
```

but I don't get the "value" field.

I tried every possibility which came into my mind, like:

```
    return $this->format->parameters->value;
    return $this->format->parameters['value'];
```

and many useless things more...

Maybe one of you has more in mind.
Thanks!

Comment: Parameters is an array so you will need to add in the key. For example:  return $this->format->parameters[0]->value;

Comment: Cheers, that's it. Time to make a break... @DavidJones

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code:

```
return $this->format->parameters[0]->value;
```

`parameters` is an array and the value is in position 0

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
return $this->format->parameters[0]->value;
```